# Will ASP.NET Windows Authentication work with 3rd party application on same network?

Tags: asp.net, windows, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I have an intranet ASP.NET WebAPI application providing a REST API and we want to use Windows authentication to secure the URLs by setting allowed groups in the web.config like:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
       <allow roles = "someGroup1"/>
       <allow roles = "Somegroup2"/>
       <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
</authentication>
```

From [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication) page it sounds like this will fit our needs, but there is one issue I am not sure about: If we have an existing 3rd party application (not .NET) that is on the same network that consumes our REST service, will running this application as a user account who is a member of an allowed group allow the application to connect to the REST API successfully? From the asp.net site:

> For .NET client applications, the HttpClient class supports Windows authentication:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = true
};

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

It looks like you have to take some special steps inside a client application to authenticate using Windows credentials.

Does anybody know if this solution will work or there is a workaround to allow 3rd party applications to authenticate using Windows credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application is running on a separate server this won't work unless you are running in a kerberos environment.  What you are describing is a two hop scenario that is not supported in the default windows authentication environment.  Basically, by default, an application can't take the security credential from one server and go to another server with it.  Google two-hop security and you'll find plenty of information on why it doesn't work.

Comment: So are you saying that having an application run as a specific user is equivalent to impersonation and that's why this won't work because Windows won't delegate impersonated credentials?

Comment: Also, I don't need to use the credentials of the user who is using the 3rd party application to access the REST API, it is sufficient for my 3rd party application to just be "hardcoded" as a single user and use those credentials... does the same situation still apply?

Comment: If you hardcoded values into the application, that would work because you are creating a new set of credentials from the app to the REST service.  You can't, however, take credentials into the app and go somewhere else with them unless you have a kerberos enabled environment.

Comment: Ok, one more thing then... if I can't change the code of the application, will running the application (like doing Run As..) as a certain user work in this case? Or is that considered impersonation/delegating credentials?